# Passing variable value from one class to another Java

Tags: java, class, dialog

How would I go about passing a variable value from one class to another without creating a new object instance?
Basically, I have these client and server classes and I want to transfer the client username value to the server class so each user can be recognized in the "sendToAll" server method.

Client class:

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package chat;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Allura
 */
public class ChatClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    BufferedReader reader;
    PrintWriter writer;
    String username;
    /**
     * Creates new form ChatClient
     */
    public ChatClient() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        messageBox = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        inputBox = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        sendButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        messageBox.setEditable(false);
        messageBox.setColumns(20);
        messageBox.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(messageBox);

        sendButton.setText("Send");
        sendButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                sendButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(inputBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 462, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(sendButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 118, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 353, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(inputBox)
                    .addComponent(sendButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(23, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void sendButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        if(!inputBox.getText().equals(""))
        {
            try
            {
                writer.println(inputBox.getText());
                writer.flush();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
        client.go();
    }
    public void go()
    {
        username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter a username: ");
        setUpNetwork();
        setVisible(true);
        Thread myRunner = new Thread(new MessageReader());
        myRunner.start();
    }
    public void setUpNetwork()
    {
        try
        {
            Socket sock = new Socket("0.0.0.0", 5000);
            InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(input);
            writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Connection established.");
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public class MessageReader implements Runnable
    {
        String message;
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    messageBox.append(message + "\n");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField inputBox;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea messageBox;
    private javax.swing.JButton sendButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Server class:

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package chat;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Allura
 */
public class ChatServer extends JFrame {
    ArrayList StreamOutput;
    Socket mainSocket;
    
    public class ClientHandler implements Runnable
    {
        Socket sock;
        BufferedReader reader;
        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSock)
        {
            try
            {
                sock = clientSock;
                InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(input);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void run()
        {
            String message;
            try
            {
                while((message = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sendToAll(message);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ChatServer().go();
    }
    public void go()
    {
        StreamOutput = new ArrayList();
        try
        {
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
            while(true)
            {
                mainSocket = serverSock.accept();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(mainSocket.getOutputStream());
                StreamOutput.add(writer);
                System.out.println("Request from client accepted. Connection established.");
                Thread myRunner = new Thread(new ClientHandler(mainSocket));
                myRunner.start();
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void sendToAll(String message)
    {
        Iterator it = StreamOutput.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            try
            {
                PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next();
                writer.println(message);
                writer.flush();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This kind of depends on the structure of your program.

Comment: In server/client relations usually over the network via sockets

Comment: Posted server and client code. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with two different processes (client and server) which communicate via sockets there is no way to prevent new objects form being created.

I guess title and problem description are a little misleading.